# Get the List of Visible Items from a Pivot Field using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, pivotitem

I'm using the below code to loop through a pivot field for getting the pivot items which are visible. But the `pivotitem.count` gives a 0 when the pivot field is in **Row Label**    When I move this pivot field to Column Label, the code is working fine. But I NEED this Field to stay on row label.

Is there any work around for my problem?

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pvtitem As PivotItem

Set nwSheet = Worksheets.Add
nwSheet.Activate
rw = 0

Set pt = Sheets("Reasons").PivotTables("PivotFields")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Characteristics].[Reason].[Reason]")

With pf
    For i = 0 To .PivotItems.Count
        rw = rw + 1
        nwSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value = .PivotItems.Count
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating on RowFields, explicitly, can get a handle on visible Pivot Items in Row Fields.
Please see if this serves the purpose:

```
    Set pt = Sheets("Reasons").PivotTables("PivotFields")
    Dim pf As PivotField
    For Each pf In pt.RowFields
          MsgBox pf.Name & " : " & pf.VisibleItems.Count
    Next
```

To iterate on Report Filter:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pFilter As PivotFilter
Dim pFilters As PivotFilters
Dim pF As PivotField

Set pt = Sheets("Reasons").PivotTables("PivotFields")
'Set the first RowField as the PivotField
Set pF = pt.RowFields(1)

'Remove previous filters
pF.ClearAllFilters

'Assuming we have a RowField as 'Quarter' and DataField as 'Sum of Sale',
'we can apply a new 'ValueIsLessThan' filter for a Sum of Sale value of 12000

pt.PivotFields("Quarter").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsLessThan, _
DataField:=pt.PivotFields("Sum of Sale"), Value1:=12000

Set pFilters = pt.PivotFields("Quarter").PivotFilters

For Each pFilter In pFilters
  MsgBox "Filter Applied On: " & pFilter.PivotField.Name & " -- Filtered values for less than : " & pFilter.Value1
Next
```

Comment: Nope. That's not working. For loop is just getting skipped. So I assume it is unable to fetch the Pivot Fields as well

Comment: It worked like this: For Each pi In pt.RowFields(1).PivotItems

Comment: I'm also trying to fetch the fields in the Report Filter using "pt.Filter(1).PivotItems" but that's not working. Do you have any idea how to work with Pivot Fields in Report Filter?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to do in Report Filter.. I don't want to clear the filters. I just want to count the no.of items in each pivot field in the Report Filter

Comment: Did you try something like:
        Dim pI as PivotItem
        For Each pI In pFilter.PivotField.PivotItems
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & pI.Name
        Next
        MsgBox msg